# Add void addFoodFirst(String foodName) with ONLY 1 statement to add foodName at the beginning of foods as the very FIRST element

Tags: java

*This is not homework or a test for any class, just extra studying for my own cause* 
This is the code I have already implemented

```
    /**
     * adds food to the list 
     * @param String foodName
     * @param int index 
     */
    public void addFood(int index, String foodName)
    {
        foods.add(foodName);
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    public void addFoodFirst(String foodName)
    {

    }
```

Not sure about how to go at this statement.

Comment: What type of object is `foods`, a String array or maybe a `java.util.Collection` of some sort?

Comment: foods is a string type of an arraylist

Comment: How does `foods.add(foodName)` add `foodName` at index `index`? Why only one statement?

Comment: For the first addFood it was just to add a food into the array list but the second addFood it is saying to make it add the food as the first one in the array list

Comment: `foods.add(0, foodName)` should work. Refer to the doc of `ArrayList`

Comment: I used an early project I did which was a music organizer that used files of a string array list and to add a filename thats the exact way I did it for the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `foods` is an `ArrayList` you can just use the [`add(int, E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) method to add an element at the beginning, like this:

```
public void addFoodFirst(String foodName) {
  foods.add(0, foodName);
}
```

Comment: this will add the food as the first spot in the array list but then is the first addFood method right?

Comment: by just having foods.add(foodName);

Comment: The first method would add an item to the end of the list.

Comment: I ran the program and it worked perfectly thank you for the quick response I understand now what its saying so I can change the 0 with any number and it will place that string in that position

Comment: @lilgudo If it's working can you accept the answer?